# How to stub mongoose model save *and* it's save hooks

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose

Why does this code fail with the "you should have stubbed me" error message instead of just printing "Save stub called" and exiting?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  modelSchema,
  ModelClass,
  modelInstance;

modelSchema = new Schema({name: {type: String}});
modelSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  throw new Error('you should have stubbed me');
});
ModelClass = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema);
ModelClass.prototype.save = function () { console.log('Save stub called'); }
modelInstance = new ModelClass();
modelInstance.save();
```

I've seen this method of stubbing a model's save function pretty commonly recommended so I'm surprised it doesn't prevent the pre-save hooks also being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `Schema.prototype.pre = function () {};` solved this.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  modelSchema,
  ModelClass,
  modelInstance;

Schema.prototype.pre = function () {};
modelSchema = new Schema({name: {type: String}});
modelSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  throw new Error('you should have stubbed me');
});
ModelClass = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema);
ModelClass.prototype.save = function () { console.log('Save stub called'); }
modelInstance = new ModelClass();
modelInstance.save();
```